# TikZ change spacing between double arrow tip

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to create a double arrow tip (latex' style) but the tips get spaced a little too far apart.  I'd like them closer.  Any way to change this spacing?

MWE Below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,arrows.spaced}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Default behavior
\draw [->>,>=latex',ultra thick] (0,0) -- (1.0,0);

% Desired behavior
\draw [->,>=latex',ultra thick] (0,-0.25) -- (0.85,-0.25);
\draw [->,>=latex',ultra thick] (0,-0.25) -- (1.0,-0.25);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Top arrow is default behavior, bottom arrow is desired behavior.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing with the sep-key. I also changed to the new names of arrows.meta:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [-{Latex[]Latex[]},ultra thick] (0,0) -- (1.0,0);


\draw [-{Latex[sep=-2mm]Latex[]},ultra thick] (0,-1) -- (1.0,-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]